# Install Visual Studio Code on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I installed Visual Studio Code on Linux Mint using the software manager. The problem is that I can not run VSC using the terminal, normally on windows I would use code . on the project I want to run. Now in Linux Mint it is telling me that the command code. does not exist.

Can someone please give some insight about how to use VSC on Linux Mint?

Comment: If you open a new terminal and type `dpkg -s code` what does it show?

Comment: If you open a new terminal and type `dpkg -s code` what does it show?

Comment: The version in the Software Manager is a [Flatpak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak) package and not supported by Microsoft. I would recommend installing the .deb from the [official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).

Comment: install from the .deb on the official website in @user3885596 's comment. Works fine. open a terminal window and the code command works fine also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install it with Snap

https://snapcraft.io/install/code/mint

or download it directly from website

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score 1):

Download it directly from Microsoft website. Worked for me pretty good.